# Need a sample on how to connect to a different system from the WEB application which is in the network?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I developed an Web application which reads some data from the files from different systems in the network.As its a web application it can be used any where in the network ,,,,so my question is how do i connect to a different system by entering an ipaddress or systemname which are in the network.

currently i am able to connect to a different system/machine by changing the value in my web.config file manually(which is not a good practice).

Is there any generic idea on which i can follow to achieve what i am expecting rather than changing the web.config file.

Comment: you developed the application, right? so you must know how the application ineracts with the config file, and it follows that you would know how to accomplish the same without a config file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956756/update-web-config-file-in-asp-net people gave you answers, and are trying to help; you have to try to learn.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx I have been working on the scenario which i already posted but unable to figure out a way to accomplish it.The reason why i posted my question again is because i thought that i didn't frame my question earlier ?

Comment: so you aren't actually making the HTTP connections yourself, right? and you need to know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example, I don't know how current or how accurate: http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/HttpWebFetch.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link ,i will try to implement the sample which you gave me.